# Nested authorization support in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, nested, authorization

A system has nested resources. For example

```
Farm HasMany Sectors
```

An example object relation will be like below

```
farm1 => [sector1]
farm2 => [sector2, sector3]
```

Now say, `user1` has read,write permission on `farm1`.

```
user1 Has(read,write) on farm1
```

I need the system to automatically use the access for all the nested resources of `farm1`, in this case `sector1`.

In other words, something like `user1.hasWritePermisson(sector1)` should return true, though the ACL is actually stored with `farm1`. I need this even to work on the nested resources of sector and so on.

A straightforward solution would probably be to copy the access to all of the children objects of farm1 at the updating its acl. But I believe this would be a really inefficient one if farm1 contains thousands of sectors.

What would be the best way to achieve this in **symfony2**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all. I think your question has nothing to do with SF2. In my opinion, you should create a efficient database which helps you to do the task. The rest is only a few queries away.

As I understand, it will be 3 major objects: `User`, `Farm` and `Sector`.

`User could be in many Farms and Farms could be seen/wrote by many users`

`A Farm has many sectors, but a sector can only be in one farm`

That being clarified, you will also need to declare the permissions for every user has in a farm. But, this will be declared in the many-to-many relationship with two relationship properties (read, write).

Once everything well designed, you should be able to create queries that satisfy your needs.

I know it's hard to understand because I'm talking in abstract, but let me know if you don't understand and I will draw you a scheme.

Comment: Firstly, yes technically theres nothing to do with SF2. But the project will be using symfony2 framework. Sometimes frameworks provide beautiful ways to handle such complex but common stuffs. The `User`, `Farm`, `Sector` structure you mentioned is exact. Please note that the user will not be explicitely added to a farm/sector/somethingelse object. Hence there will not be any relationship table like `FARM_USER`. This access is expected to be achieved by the ACL.